# XRI Discovery for Open Id

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth, xri

According to the Open ID specs (http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#discovery). The discovery process takes place in 3 ways:

1. XRI Discovery
2. Yadis Discovery
3. HTML Discovery

How do you do an XRI discovery? Let's say I have the xri, that being `=example` since I stripped the `xri://`. What am I supposed to do with that xri? How do I get the XRDS document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. XRDS is basically an XML document. The XRI is basically a login uri.

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://docs.oasis-open.org/xri/2.0/specs/xri-resolution-V2.0.html

A proxy resolver is available at http://xri.net/